# Isolating string that is contained elsewhere

Tags: python

I'm setting up a script to merge PDFs based on text contained in their filename. The issue I have here is that "Violin I" is also contained in "Violin II", and "Alto Saxophone I" is also contained in "Alto Saxophone II". How do I set this up so tempList will only contain entries from "Violin I" and exclude "Violin II", and vice-versa?

```
pdfList = ["01 Violin I.pdf", "02 Violin I.pdf","01 Violin II.pdf", "02 Violin II.pdf",  ]
instruments = ["Soprano", "Tenor", "Violin I", "Violin II", "Viola", "Cello", "Contrabass", "Alto Saxophone I", "Alto Saxophone II", "Tenor Saxophone", "Baritone Saxophone"]


# create arrays for each instrument that can be used for merging/organization
def organizer():
    for fileName in pdfList:
        for instrument in instruments:
            tempList = []
            if instrument in fileName:
                tempList.append(fileName)
        print tempList


print pdfList
organizer()
```

Comment: Are the PDFs always named like this?  Ie. `Number+Instrument+.pdf`.  Or should we assume that the PDF can have any name that includes the instrument?

Comment: Yes, the PDFs will always be in format "(initial number) + (some text) + (instrument) +.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making this change:

```
...
if instrument+'.pdf' in fileName:
...
```

Would this cover all situations?

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid including substrings would be to use a regex like:

```
import re

pdfList = ["01 Violin I.pdf", "02 Violin I.pdf","01 Violin II.pdf", "02 Violin \
II.pdf",  ]
instruments = ["Soprano", "Tenor", "Violin I", "Violin II", "Viola", "Cello", "\
Contrabass", "Alto Saxophone I", "Alto Saxophone II", "Tenor Saxophone", "Barit\
one Saxophone"]

# create arrays for each instrument that can be used for merging/organization   
def organizer():
    for fileName in pdfList:
        tempList = []
        for instrument in instruments:
            if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(instrument), fileName):
                tempList.append(fileName)
        print tempList

print pdfList
organizer()
```

This wraps your search term with `\b` so that it only matches if the beginning and end are on word boundaries. Also, perhaps obvious but worth pointing out, this will also make your instrument names part of the regex, so be mindful if you use any chars that are also regex metacharacters they'll be interpreeted as such (right now you're not). A more general scheme would require some code to find and properly escape such characters.